# Variable in routine is private - cannot call it outside of routine - Javascript

Tags: javascript

If I alert title like this, title is alerted correctly and has a value.

```
var myRequest = new Request('URL');
var title;
   fetch(myRequest).then(function(text) {
        return response.text().then(function(text) {
             title= text; 
             alert (title);

        });
   });
```

If I alert title like this - outside of the routine, the variable title is empty/undefined.

```
var myRequest = new Request('URL');
var title;
   fetch(myRequest).then(function(text) {
        return response.text().then(function(text) {
             title= text; 

        });
   });

 alert (title);
```

I need to alert title outside of the fetch routine.

I tried declaring the variable inside the routine and giving the variable the fetch routine title = fetch(myRequest)...  Nothing worked.

What am I doing wrong? Where is the error?

Note: I've hidden the URL that is being fetched in this post. The fetching works fine.

Comment: Umm, isn't the `fetch` and `then` executed asynchronously? I'd expect the `alert` showed long before the request actually finished fetching. Try keeping the `alert` in both places, I'm pretty sure the undefined one executes first (that is, before you even assign `title`).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript), [How to return response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321), etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not about scope, it's about *timing*. The code after your `fetch` call runs **before** the operation the `fetch` call started finishes, and so runs **before** your callback is called.

If you want to use `title` elsewhere, you need to call the code doing it from within your callback, e.g.:

```
var myRequest = new Request('URL');
var title;
fetch(myRequest).then(function(text) {
    return response.text().then(function(text) {
        title= text; 
        doSomethingWithTitle();
    });
});

function doSomethingWithTitle() {
    alert(title);
}
```

---

I'm a bit confused by the `return response.text().then(...` part of your code, but I've left it above on the assumption that it's correct. But it's really suspicious. :-)

Comment: I tried that - http://jsfiddle.net/vkweuqo4/  - so, I've the fetch + title is feeding into the listener (function (event)). The code is part of a service worker for push. I still get title as undefined even though i've defined event();

Comment: I also tried putting the entire listener into the fetch function - didn't work.

Comment: @CodyRaspien: That fiddle doesn't remotely do what the answer suggests. If you actually do what the answer suggests, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/ytpphpt3/

Answer (score 0):

Your `alert(title)` is invoked immediately after your `fetch` call starts off the Promise chain. Your promises haven't been fulfilled.

Comment: how do i get around this? a timer?

Comment: You don't want to use a timer for that, as it negates the entire Promise system. Either chain another promise onto the end, or just keep your `alert` inside as you have up top. Though, that can depend on what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: @CodyRaspien: A timer would involve a callback. You already *have* a callback that you know has the `title` (the one you're passing into `then`). So just use that callback.

Comment: What if I do the fetch in a separate script and then importscripts (that js) into the above script? Would that solve the issue? The fetch would run before in its own script prior to calling title in the main script? Thoughts?

Comment: The problem is that the Promise is asynchronous, so it can return whenever. I would invoke whatever function you have within that last Promise with the data that gets returned (such as your `title` variable).